# How to return last 5 rows by date

Tags: php, mysql

How do I return the 5 most recent rows (by date) from a table ordered from oldest to newest.

I.E.

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE postid like '$topic_id'
ORDER BY postdate DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Returns:

```
reply 10
reply 9
reply 8
reply 7
reply 6
```

And:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE postid like '$topic_id'
ORDER BY postdate ASC LIMIT 5");
```

Returns:

```
reply 1
reply 2
reply 3
reply 4
reply 5
```

---

How do I return?

```
reply 6
reply 7
reply 8
reply 9
reply 10
```

Comment: Another way would be to use: ORDER BY posts.postdate ASC LIMIT 5,10");

Comment: That is only any good if you always have 10 rows. The answer given by @Barmar is better and will always give the 5 newest rows in reverse order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the most recent rows, then order it the other way in the main query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM posts
      WHERE postid like '$topic_id'
      ORDER BY postdate DESC LIMIT 5) x
ORDER BY postdate ASC
```

To answer the inevitable question, `x` is an alias for the subquery, because MySQL requires all subqueries in joins to be named with aliases.

Comment: Simple, elegant, and well explained. +1 from me.

Comment: To see what x does, try it without the x